# Footer is dividing content

Tags: html, css

I have a footer on a page that is taking content and placing some of it on top and then some of it on the bottom. I don't know why its doing this, I tried putting `clear:both;` on both the `mainWrap` and the `footer`, but it didn't help.

HTML -

```
<div id="mainWrap">
 <h1>Welcome to ASA.</h1>
 <hr class="faded">
 <h3>Register</h3>
 <form action="register.php" method="post">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><p>Username:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>Password:</p></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>Repeat Password:</p></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="rpassword" id="rpassword" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>Email:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>Skype Username:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="skypeuser" id="skypeuser" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>First Name:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>Last Name:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit" maxlength="50" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS -

```
#mainWrap {
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}

#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    clear:both;
    left:0;
    bottom:0; 
    background-color:#fff;
    height:160px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Picture of whats happening - 
[image: Image of whats happening]

Comment: Why is the footer positioned absolutely?

Comment: your `<hr>` is not closed. seems odd to me, even though it is ok in plain HTML, unless you are specifically using HTML and not XHTML I wouldn't get into the habit of leaving tags open like that.

Comment: Hr is a self closing tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#bottom {}`  problem lies here where your position is `absolute` and also `bottom:0` with `height:160px` which is glueing the footer to the bottom having a height of 160px.

Answer (score 0):

Op the problem was with the position absolute for the `<div id="bottom"></div>` here is the updated jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HxCL9/